# Angular Directive templateUrl Not Working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to work with creating a config that I can use across my whole app. I have created a test real quick to see if it will work and it does in a directive I have created as long as the template is used and not templateUrl. When I try to use external template it does not work. Please have a look at this and help me to know what it is that I am doing wrong or can make better.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSeIGKtbfIoaZFtshDaB?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `template` it works because you are building the HTML as a string in Javascript.

When using `templateUrl` you are using `template.html`, which contains HTML. This means that for example `config.dev.name` will be considered normal text, and will not be evaluated.

You can make the `config` available in the scope and use interpolation to get the correct values.

Javascript:

```
myApp.directive('directive', function(config) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.config = config;
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{config.dev.name}}<br>Version: {{config.dev.version}}</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help and better understanding of the template and templateUrl